# How to get numbers in a string separated with commas and save each of them in an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, string

I have a string of `ID's` wherein they're being separated with commas.
For example, the string is:
`"15,14,12,13"`

How can I extract the numbers/id's from this string and save each of them in a `JSON` or array to be something like this

```
Array: {
   15,
   14,
   12,
   13
}
```

I don't know how it's done using `regex` or string manipulation. Please advice.

Comment: string.split(',') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### use `split` & `map` & `parseInt` methods.

```js
var numbers="15,14,12,13";
var result=numbers.split(',').map(function(number){
  return parseInt(number);
});
console.log('convert '+JSON.stringify(numbers)+" to array:"+JSON.stringify(result));
```

### Use `eval` method

```js
var numbers="15,14,12,13";
var result=eval("["+numbers+"]");
console.log('convert '+JSON.stringify(numbers)+" to array:"+JSON.stringify(result));
```